# Chrome on Android: no HTTP Request header - Range: bytes=0-

Tags: android, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, android-contentprovider

I got an mp4 file which is streaming thru an http handler to most browsers, except Chrome on Android, tried version 32 and 36 (the latest at this point)

seems Chrome is not sending the HTTP Request Header
Range: bytes=0-

this is what the handler is looking for to start off the chunked streaming.

Is there a way to force Chrome to send this header when the mp4 file is
inside a  tag.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What do you mean with "mp4 file is inside a tag"? In general, all streaming requires HTTP server to support RFC 7233 and respond with status HTTP 206 for the streaming to work correctly. In addition, I'd highly recommend only serving streaming files over HTTP/2 with Chrome because it has bugs with media streaming over HTTP/1 (in some cases Chrome fails to teardown existing connections and cannot handle any new requests to the server).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Chrome v36 on Android 4.3 is requesting mp4 with a 200.

if delivering from a HttpHandler there are issues if you read Session information from the context with IRequiresSessionState